# Jonathan Oliver's EventStore Querying and Projections

Tags: neventstore

In the screecast presentation Jonathan Oliver gave regarding his EventStore implementation He mentioned the ability to query the events, for example to make a complex temporal query. From what I understand this is done through updating a read model or creating projections after the eventstore is updated - however I can't seem to see any examples of this using the J.O's implementation. Any links to or examples would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The querying mechanism of EventStore v3.x is a little...sub par at this stage.  But technically speaking, that was never the intended purpose of the EventStore in the first place.  Instead, it was to persist the events and make them available for future use.  That being said, you're welcome to use whatever querying mechanism you feel is necessary to pull the events out of the underlying data store and to run them through your code to "project" the events into a particular view or read model.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. The question arose from my need to do temporal database queries similar to the ones you mentioned in your eventstore screencast. In my eventstore I am using timestamp, user, aggregate type and aggregate id columns, as well as a column for the event blob. It seems to me that if we use a blob to store the event, we cannot query over any of the blob properties. You would only be able to query over the actual eventstore columns. Is this what you had in mind when you gave the temporal database query example in your talk: http://vimeo.com/31153808

Comment: If you want to query over event properties, then you'll need to have a more specific storage system.  Basically you're going to need a given table per event type to store and index the various properties.

Comment: No, the EventStore doesn't support anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Article that describes temporal query is e.g. http://codeofrob.com/entries/evented-github-adventure---temporal-queries,-who-doesnt-trust-their-hardware.html
It is based on projections and you can see a nice example there.